# Product space on a metric space

Tags: metric-spaces

The following has been lectured

> Defn (Product Spaces) For any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and metric spaces $\left(M_k, d_k\right)$ for $k \in\{1, \ldots, n\}$, we define the product space
> $$
> \left(\bigoplus_{k=1}^n M_k\right)_p=M_1 \oplus_p \cdots \oplus_p M_n=\left(M_1 \times \cdots \times M_n, d_p\right) .
> $$
> Example (Product spaces) We have that $\mathbb{R} \oplus_1 \mathbb{R}=\ell_1^2$.
> Remark $\mathbb{R} \oplus \mathbb{R} \oplus \mathbb{R}$ doesn't make sense since we have not defined the associativity of the $\oplus$ operator. The two choices yield different metric spaces.

Here
$$
d_p (x,y) = \left(  \sum_{i=1}^{n} \ (d_i (x_i, y_i))^{p} \right)^{1/p}
$$

---

I am struggling to understand both the definition and the example given. In the definition, does it tell us that $M_1 \times \cdots \times M_n$ is the "Set" and $d_p$ is the metric? Moreover, if so, why doesn't $\mathbb{R} \oplus \mathbb{R} \oplus \mathbb{R}$ make sense? Should it not be $\ell _1 ^3$?

If anybody could clarify that for me I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I think in its current form, the definition is not complete. Probably $M_1\times \cdots \times M_n$ is the underlying set, and $d_p$ is the metric, but the definition of $d_p$ needs to be specified.

Comment: I have the definition for $d_p$ in this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4673519/why-is-d-infty-leq-d-2-leq-d-1-leq-2-d-infty.

Comment: I think my main issue with the above is why, or whether, the remark is true.

Comment: You should add the definition here so that the reader does not have to consult your other question.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I have now done so.

Comment: Except that what you wrote makes no sense as written, you should replace $|x_i-y_i|$ with $d_i(x_i,y_i)$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan good spot!

Comment: The remark is silly. $(M_1\oplus_p M_2)\oplus_p M_3$ and $M_1\oplus_p(M_2\oplus_p M_3)$ are both naturally isomorphic (isometrically) to $\left(\bigoplus_{k=1}^3M_k\right)_p.$

Comment: The remark is irritating, because without a subscript specifying $p$, $M_1 \oplus M_2$ doesn't even specify a metric.