# Why is $d_{\infty} \leq d_2 \leq d_1 \leq 2 d_{\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

The following was lectured to me

> Proposition 4.1 (Important result) Let $d_1, d_2, d_{\infty}$ be
> metrics on $\mathbf{R}^n$. Then $$ d_{\infty} \leq d_2 \leq d_1 \leq 2
>  d_{\infty} $$

The definitions are
$$
d_p (x,y) = \left(  \sum_{i=1}^{n} \ |x_i -y_i|^{p} \right)^{1/p} \;\;
d_\infty (x,y) = \sup_{i=1,..., n}{ |x_i - y_i| }.
$$

I see why $d_\infty \leq d_2 \leq d_1$ however, I do not see why $ d_1 \leq 2 d_\infty$. This should be something trivial but I can't seem to figure it out. Could some help me see why it is true?

**Remark:** I seem to only be able  to prove $d_1 \leq n d_\infty$.

Comment: It has to be $n=2$; otherwise, the vectors $x=(1, 1, \dots ,1)$ and $y=0$ are a counterexample. Or you modify the statement.

Comment: When you can't find a way to prove something, start looking for a counterexample.

Comment: Thank you for the answers,  I see now.  @F.Conrad can you post this comment as an answer so that I can accept it and mark the post as answered?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you assigned the algebra-precalculus tag to this question.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro because it also seemed like an algebra statement.

Comment: [Precalculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precalculus) consists of school algebra and trigonometry topics that one would study before beginning the study of calculus. Your question is 1-3 years of mathematics study beyond (elementary) calculus (even multivariable). Better tags are [metric-spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metric-spaces) and [inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inequality). FYI, for more context about your question see [these questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=equivalence+of+metrics+site%3Amath.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to be $n=2$; otherwise, the vectors $x=(1,1,…,1)$ and $y=0$ are a counterexample. Or you modify the statement.

We check that
$$
d_1(x-y)=n\cdot |1-0|=n
$$
$$
d_{\infty}(x-y)=1
$$
and so the inequality
$$
d_1(x,y)=n \leq 2 \cdot 1= d_{\infty}(x,y)
$$
is violated for $n>2$.